# Should the whole home page be inside main tag?

Tags: html

Lets say I have a website like [apple](http://apple.com). So should the red section go inside the main tag or the green section?

[image]

Comment: red section can remain in `header` gray background area at the bottom in `footer` and the middle portion can remain in `main` section.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary. You can keep the upper part in the header, the middle part in main and bottom part in footer. Generally these tags are not used